# Optimize query for yii2

Tags: mysql, optimization, yii2, query-builder

this query is getting the right data i want, but this is so slow and heavy on our server, with only 5417 rows of data. how would i optimize this query in query builder or yii2 framework way?

```
SELECT  t1.id
    FROM  tbl_ticket t1
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT  1
            FROM  tbl_ticket
            WHERE  parent_id = t1.id 
        )
      AND  parent_id =0
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  MAX( id )
    FROM  tbl_ticket
    WHERE  parent_id <>0
    GROUP BY  parent_id
    ORDER BY  id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT  t1.id
    FROM      tbl_ticket t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ticket t2  ON  t2.parent_id = t1.id 
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
      AND t1.parent_id = 0 )
UNION  ALL 
( SELECT  MAX( id )
    FROM  tbl_ticket
    WHERE  parent_id <> 0
    GROUP BY  parent_id )
ORDER BY id ASC
```

The first `SELECT` seems to be finding ids that have no children and no parents.  Correct?

The second `SELECT` seems to be finding the last sibling in each family, excluding Adam and Eve.  Is that what you intended?

I added parentheses to move the `ORDER BY` away from the second `SELECT` to the entire query.  Is that what you intended?

To make that query run 'fast', you need

```
INDEX(parent_id, id)
```

I assume, you already have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_ticket`.)

Answer (score 0):

here is the table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_ticket` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `r_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `d_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hd_user_username` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `hd_user_email` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  `attachment` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `room_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `gsm` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `file_mime_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `file_original_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_size` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_extension` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acknowledged` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hostname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `useragent` text,
  `closing_remark` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_student` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `installation` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5428 ;